# Binance - Convert Stablecoin to Stablecoin (e.g. from USDT to BUSD) using API (CCXT, or Binance)

Tags: binance-api-client, ccxt

I can not find support for converting USDT to BUSD or vise versa in any python package (CCXT, python-binance...).

Answer (score 2):

I have a reply.

1. You need to complete a questionnaire to request for access to
   Binance Convert API.
2. Then you just access the requests trough CCTX
   using :

`

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({'apiKey': PKEY, 'secret': SKEY})
amount = decimal.Decimal('20')
params = {'fromAsset': 'USDT', 'toAsset': 'BUSD', 'fromAmount': amount}
response = exchange.sapi_post_convert_getquote(params)
```

`